# Is my project uploaded to a repository when using Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am new in Maven. I think its a very helpful tool. Local repository is automatically filled with .jars neededs on my project.

But I know that it can also work in both directions: your own project has an IdArtifact (designed in pom.xml file), and can be uploaded to a public server. Some times is usefull when you want to develop a public project, but, how to ensure that your project wont be upload to public repository, in pom.xml? and vice-versa?

Maybe its an unfounded concern, but sometimes IDE (like netbeans, that im using), do things without monitoring it. I am a bit "scared" with that. I wont publish some private libraries.

Comment: The truly public repositories are read-only. Trust me, you can't accidentally publish.

Comment: Is it sure? Servers that I am using are: http://oss.sonatype.org/ and http://download.java.net/maven/2/ and http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ Are they secure?

Comment: If you won't take my word for it, try it yourself. Make a "play" maven project. Run `mvn deploy` and see what happens.

Comment: [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project tutorial:tutorial:${project.version}

Comment: So, I can't accidentally publish my private project :-P Trust you. But, whats the way to publish a library that i want to make public if is not possible?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy
deploy (default-deploy) on project WebApplDietLib: Deployment failed
 element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement
n -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]

Comment: What "distributionManagement" means?

Comment: @Raph.  Let us first decide what your question is.  From the comments, it has deviated from concern on your project getting deployed to knowing how to deploy your project. Please edit your question suitably.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Raghuram: One point at a time ;-) So regarding your question

> Some times is usefull when you want to develop a public project, but, how to ensure that your project wont be upload to public repository, in pom.xml?

my answer is: In case you have no [DistributionManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) Section configured in your pom.xml including the parent, if you have one (if you don't know about that perhaps start reading [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)), you are safe. To deploy to a repository (public or not) it would have to be configured in the [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers).

Comment: Most people uses Maven just to manage their own private projects. So, I think this distribution management configuration is just and only used when you are developing a GPL or open project. For an internal enterprise project, it's not the case. Its wht I asked that :-P Maybe a newbe question.

Comment: @Raph: Well, you could (perhaps [should](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/sect-repoman-reasons.html)) setup a Nexus or other repository manager in your company (or even if you're private but ambitous ;-) and will then also need this.